# Retrieve binary data from SQLite database with dapper

Tags: c#, arrays, sqlite, dapper

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of an SQLite database using Dapper ORM and populate a list of objects using it. However, even though I have set the column type in the database to `BLOB`, I am getting an error which seems to suggest Dapper ORM is interpreting the data as a string.

The database is being populated with a Python script which is configured with the column also set to `BLOB` type. Within SQLiteStudio, I can view the data as an image preview, so the correct data is in the database.

The error:
[image]

The code to query the database:

```cs
public List<Thumbnail> ReadAll()
{
    var test = _dbConnection.Query<Thumbnail>(
                "Select * FROM thumbcache").ToList();       
    return test;
}
```

Here is my class definition:

```cs
public class Thumbnail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime scantime { get; set; }
    public int imageheight { get; set; }
    public int imagewidth { get; set; }
    public string identifier { get; set; }
    public long offset { get; set; }
    public string signature { get; set; }
    public int entrySize { get; set; }
    public int identifierlen { get; set; }
    public long datasize { get; set; }
    public int paddingsize { get; set; }
    public string datachecksum { get; set; }
    public string headerchecksum { get; set; }
    public string entryhash { get; set; }
    public string cachefile { get; set; }
    public byte[] image { get; set; }   // This is the field that fails to be populated
}
```

The data in the database:
[image]

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? I'd appreciate any suggestions you may have.

In response to @MarcGravell's comment, I am now trying to save the binary as base64 in the database and parse it using C#, however I am getting most images throw invalid base64 errors (even though the base64 in the database is correct), and the images that do show are corrupt/incorrect.

Class definition:

```cs
public class Thumbnail
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    ...
    public string cachefile { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }   //Changed this to string
}
```

Current output of my C# (value of base64 string pulled straight from db shown in messagebox):
[image]

What is interesting to note is that the MessageBox is supposed to show the base64 pulled from the database, yet it seems to show bytes instead?

And this is what the image looks like when you directly convert the base64 in the database into an image using an online tool:

[image]

My code to create the image:

```cs
private Image create_image(Thumbnail thumb)
{
    string imageBase64 = thumb.image;
    MessageBox.Show(imageBase64);
    try
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageBase64)
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
        {
            Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return image;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the error I get when I don't use a try-catch:
[image]

Comment: sqlite is... a bit of a fun one; it mostly wants everything to be a string, so I'm *guessing* that the schema here is claiming it to *be* a string, and Dapper is making some wrong choices based on what the schema is claiming

Comment: @MarcGravell Is it possible for the developer who "knows better" to "help" Dapper in any way to make a better choice?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for your reply. I have now tried using a base64 string as the method of storage in the database, however I am getting some strange errors when trying to turn the base64 into images. I have updated my question to show this. Can you see anything that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Jack Convert.FromBase64String was the correct way of parsing a base-64 encoded payload. Was the data actually base-64 encoded?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes it was base64 encoded, and to confirm this I got the base64 saved in the database and put it through an online base64 to image converter and it came out perfect. After some debugging it looks like Dapper is populating the object with binary rather than base64...? So instead of just taking the string value from the db and putting it straight into the string class variable, it seems to be converting it from base64 in between, and then still storing it in a string.

Comment: @Jack Dapper doesn't convert anything here - if the database supplies a string, it just stores it on the object. How did you *store* the value? If Convert.FromBase64String doesn't work, then: the data isn't base-64

Comment: @MarcGravell I was using `base64.b64encode(myBytes).decode('utf-8')` in python to generate the base64 data in the database, and the column type was `STRING`. The data is shown in SQLiteStudio as quite normal Base64, and when that is copy and pasted into an online 'Base64 to image converter' it seems to come back with the original image, but when it is pulled in to C# by dapper it ends up as bytes. Perhaps some background encoding issue with my Base64 that SQLiteStudio sorts out by itself?

Comment: @JackPollock well, that `decode('utf-8')` looks pretty weird there (you can't decode base-64 as utf-8 - that's using an encoding backwards) - but: is the string that you're seeing in the database the string that you're getting fom ADO.NET? emphasis: Dapper is literally just calling `GetValue(column)` here - it isn't interpreting anything

Comment: @MarcGravell I was trying to get the base64 interpretation as a straight string, rather than bytes. My understand was you could go bytes -> base64 and the base64 would be a string/ascii representation of the bytes which I could then store in the database, and then convert it back from string base64 to bytes after dapper has pulled it in?

Comment: @MarcGravell Even without the `decode('utf-8')` the base64 still seems to end up as a string containing bytes in C#

Comment: @JackPollock looking at the edits: again, this: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(imageBase64);` *is nonsensical* - that is **again**: using an encoding backwards; without things in front of me, it is very hard to give a simple "do X", but: *at multiple points* it seems you're using encodings entirely backwards - at that point: no behaviour is defined; as for the string/byte[] thing: sqlite kinda treats everything as strings, unfortunately, at least in the ADO.NET provider

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. Yeah that line was an artifact from where I was trying to figure out what was really going on with the data that being being retrieved. I've been trying to use the `Convert.FromBase64String` instead. I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @MarcGravell I've managed to fix my issue by moving from using Dapper to SQLite-Net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/). Not sure what the issue was with Dapper but SQLite-Net seems to work as expected. Thanks for your help anyway, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to fix this issue by moving from using Dapper to SQLite-Net.

https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/

Not sure what the issue with Dapper was; the data in my database was always showing correctly so I can only assume Dapper must've been doing something weird to the data when it pulled it from the database and populated the objects.

I've stuck with using Base64 encoding for the binary data, I've not tested SQLite-Net with raw binary data.